# way to Check null objects in json api array

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying a lot of things but i still can not figure out a way to Check if an object is null.
This is the Api response

[Api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRDIH.png)

The problem sometimes the object shortname Doesn't exist in the teamInfo

so there will be just "name" and "img" . i want to show some other text if shortname  Doesn't exist in teaminfo.

I've tried something like:

```
Text(
                        text = if(data.teamInfo[1].shortname != null){data.teamInfo[1].shortname}
                        else{data.teams[1]},
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .padding(5.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        maxLines = 1
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I see you are hardcoding the array index always to be `1`.  Is that right for your case?

The relevant part is this

```
    text = if (data.teamInfo[1].shortname != null) {
        data.teamInfo[1].shortname
    } else {
        data.teams[1]
    },
```

Your null check is valid, the fragment of the JSON response you gave doesn't seem to have a `teams` array so the second part may not work/compile/produce a non-null.  You do say each `teaminfo` will have a `name` so try this first

```
    text = if (data.teamInfo[1].shortname != null) {
        data.teamInfo[1].shortname
    } else {
        data.teamInfo[1].name
    },
```

And you can simply this with the "Elvis" operator

```
text = data.teamInfo[1].shortname ?: data.teamInfo[1].name
```

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention that teams array is another api response which is never null, implementing "data.teamInfo[1].shortname != null" still gives me null exception, ill try the elvis operator